# Is there any benefit to solving integrals by trig substitution this way?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Suppose we have some sort of integral like $\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ which we can solve by making the substitution $x = 2\tan(\theta)$. After performing the calculations one obtains $-\frac{\csc(\theta)}{4} + C$.

Now in back substituting we can create the right triangle based on the fact that $\tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{2}$, and obtain that $\csc(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 +4}}{x}$ which yields the final answer $-\frac{\sqrt{x^2 +4}}{4x} +C$.

I had someone mention to me today that it is also possible to just note that $\tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{2}$ implies that $\theta = \arctan(\frac{x}{2})$ and one can just substitute this in for $\theta$ into the final answer without creating a right triangle.

Besides being quicker than solving for the sides of the right triangle is there any advantage to this method? I find it harder to convince students that the two answers actually agree since their antiderivatives appear so distinct.

Comment: Why not use the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and then $-\int\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}dt=-\frac14\sqrt{1+4t^2}+C$.

Comment: They look different, but they retain the same structure. One should be able to show that $\csc \tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{4}}}{\frac{x}{2}}$

Comment: I find that a reverse substitution is a more direct approach than using a triangle. It also works when no trig is involved.

Comment: I personally prefer  creating the right triangle, aesthetically $\csc (\arctan(x/2)$ is hideous :(

Comment: More than aesthetically—trig functions of inverse trig functions are far less intuitive to understand (even their domains and limits at infinity), whereas they become far easier to understand when we write them as (square roots of) rational functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Each of the three methods has advantages and disadvantages. Different people will have different default methods. They will think those the easiest.

You have two teaching opportunities here. The first is to show that there are several equally good ways to attack this problem. The second is to reinforce the fact that an antiderivative is determined only up to a constant, and that answers that look quite different may both be correct.